# sobrecarga del operador de salida <<

Tags: c++, sobrecarga-de-operadores

Dada esta estructura:

```
struct Asignatura{
    string nombre;
    long id;
    int alumT;//numero de estudiantes que ven la asignatura
    int semestre;
    Profesor *prof;//puntero que señala la posicion de memoria del profesor que se le asigno
};
```

Y esta funcion para sobrecargar el operador <<:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &o,const Asignatura &as){
    return o<<"    "<<as.nombre<<endl<<"DATOS:"<<endl<<"ID.: " 
    <<as.id<<endl<<"Semestre: "<<as.semestre<<endl<<"Profesor: "<<as.prof- 
    >nombre<<"\n";
}
```

Como hago para agregar en `<<"Profesor: "<<as.prof->nombre` un condicional que diga:

```
if(aux1->prof!=NULL){
    cout<<"Profesor: "<<aux1->prof->nombre;
} else {
    cout<<"\nSin profesor";
}
```

Porque si no cuando se muestra una asignatura el programa se cierra porque obviamente esta tratando de acceder a un dato que no existe

*nota: cuando inserto una materia nuevo me aseguro que `prof=NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No tienes que retornar directamente el ostream en la primera línea. Por otro lado no uses `NULL` en C++ debes usar `nullptr`(para tener más detalle lee las respuestas de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr)). Además los elementos de una estructura pueden tener valores por defecto. Y por ultimo se estila que cada elemento que va a ser imprimido tenga sobrecargado ostream asi nos ahorramos líneas de código y en consecuencia tenemos un código más legible.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Profesor{
    string nombre;
};

struct Asignatura{
    string nombre;
    long id;
    int alumT;
    int semestre;
    Profesor *profesor = nullptr;
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, const Profesor &profesor){
    return o << "Profesor: "<< profesor.nombre<<"\n";
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, const Asignatura &as){
    o << as.nombre << "\nDATOS:\nID.: " << as.id << "\nSemestre: " << as.semestre <<"\n";
    if(as.profesor)
        o<< *as.profesor;
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    Profesor prof{"nombre_profesor"};
    Asignatura asig;
    asig.nombre = "nombre_de_asignatura";
    asig.id = 10;
    asig.alumT=10;
    asig.semestre = 2;
    cout<<"antes de asignar un profesor\n";
    cout<<asig;

    cout<<"despues de asignar un profesor\n";
    asig.profesor = &prof;
    cout<<asig;
    return 0;
}
```

Observación:

Muchas veces es preferible usar "\n" que "std::endl"(para más detalle lea las respuestas de [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n))

Comment: Ah ya.. lo que pasa es que como iba una condicion dentro del return pensaba que se tenia que poner `return o{... if{}...}` y me tiraba error por la llaves

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Cómo hago para agregar en un condicional que diga?:
>
> ```
> if(aux1->prof!=NULL){
>     cout<<"Profesor: "<<aux1->prof->nombre;
> } else {
>     cout<<"\nSin profesor";
> }
> ```

Los operadores de C++ son funciones como cualquier otra, la única diferencia es que se invocan con un símbolo en lugar de con una llamada función:

- *operando1* `simbolo` *operando2*.
- `símbolo(`*operando1*, *operando2*`)`.

Así que, como cualquier función, puede tener múltiples puntos de salida y puede contener cualquier código compilable. Por lo tanto:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Asignatura &as){
    o << as.nombre << ' '
      << as.id << ' '
      << as.alumT << ' '
      << as.semestre << ' ';

    if (as.prof){
        o << "Profesor: " << as.prof->nombre;
    } else {
        o << "\nSin profesor";
    }

    return o;
};
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

El operador de inyección de datos en flujo de datos (`operator <<`) se invoca cuando en el lado izquierdo del operador hay un flujo de datos (puede ser un flujo a archivo `std::ofstream` o un flujo a consola `std::cout`) y en el lado derecho el objeto sobrecargado; como primer parámetro recibirás el flujo de datos que interviene en la operación, y es el que deberás usar siempre dentro de este operador; lo digo porque has usado `std::cout` en tu ejemplo.

Se desaconseja trabajar con punteros en crudo, tu objeto `Asignatura` contiene un puntero a `Profesor` que debería ser sustituido por un [puntero inteligente](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) o por una referencia.

Comment: Oh vaya no sabia que habia ese tipo de punteros.. Siempre que pregunto algo aqui termino adquiriendo nuevas herramientas para las proyectos

Comment: @MarcelSalazar te recomiendo leer sobre los nuevos estandars C++11, C++14, C++17, parece que tu guía esta basado en una estandár antiguo.

Comment: @eyllanesc no es una guia, son las clases de la universidad, tecnicamente solo hemos visto entrada/salida, bucles/condicionales, estructuras, funciones y punteros, yo le envie ayer el borrador de mi proyecto de registro universitario y me dijo que no supo corregirlo porque no sabia que era `list <Alumno> alum`,  `for(const auto &alumno : alum) y `ostream &operator<<(ostream &o,const Alumno &a) y todo eso lo aprendi aqui` , y que para ustedes son cosas simples.

Comment: @MarcelSalazar A eso me refiero con guía(personas como un tutor/profesor, documentación, tutoriales, etc que te dan la información en que basas tu aprendizaje), que no sepa que significa `list<Alumno> alum;` me indica un desconocimiento del moderno C++ o de su poca actualización, quizas solo trabaje con C++98 que para tiempos actuales es *deprecated* :-)

Comment: @MarcelSalazar lo que comentas que el profesorado de tu universidad no está al tanto del bucle `for` de rango (añadido en el lenguaje **hace 7 años**) o la sobrecarga de operadores (que forma parte de C++ **desde el principio**) me enerva tanto que si escribo en la caja de comentarios lo que pienso de tus profesores me expulsan de la comunidad.

Comment: Por eso no me enfrasco mucho en las clases y prefiero ponerme a aprender por mi cuenta, si no, no voy a aprender nada aparte de lo basico, los de curso avanzado me habia hecho la recomendacion de que si queria programar enserio tenia que buscar por mi cuenta y no quedarme con lo que nos enseñan en la universidad.. eso es lo que estoy haciendo y el conocimiento que he adquirido equivale a dos semestres mas de la universidad.